# How does one create a permutation of strings in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, permutation

I need to create a set of permutations without repetition for an arbitrary number of strings in Powershell. The simplest example is:

```
$x = "Alpha","Beta","Charlie"
```

Output would be:

```
Alpha 
Beta 
Charlie 
Alpha Beta
Alpha Charlie
Beta Charlie
```

I haven't been able to find a useful example despite heavy Google and StackExchange searching.

Comment: OP: Unique combinations != Permutations

Answer (score -3):

I'm betting there's a cleaner way to do this, but here I'm just pulling a random number for the array key and just looping it out verifying that new random number isn't the same as the last number.

```
$x = "Alpha","Beta","Charlie"

for($i=1; $i -le 10; $i++)
{
    while ($random -eq $lastnum)
    {
        [int]$random = Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum $x.Count
    }
    $lastnum = $random

    Write-Host $x[$random]
}
```

Comment: This does not at all answer the question

Comment: I better understand it now. The original question didn't have formatting to show me he was looking for unique combinations of the available values.



It looked like he just wanted output without repetition.